# How do I import a JSON file into objectbox database on Android

Tags: gson, objectbox

I am receiving a JSON file which contains a number of entities that I wish to store in ObjectBox (Android). Is there a way to directly put the entire JSON tree into ObjectBox or is it necessary to convert the JSON into plain old Java objects and then save it to ObjectBox?

An option considered is to convert to entities using GSON.

User user = new User();
box.put(user);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, please use Jackson or GSON to convert JSON to objects first. ObjectBox does not have direct JSON APIs.

Example:

```
User user = gson.fromJson(json, User.class);
userBox.put(user);
```

For relation support, you might want to watch [this issue](https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-java/issues/104).